# Awk file not found when Setting Up Cococ2dx-3.5 environment on Windows 7

Tags: android, awk, android-ndk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to setup cocos2dx-3.5 environment on Windows 7.

Following are my values for the environment variables

```
NDK_ROOT = D:\Android\Cocos2dx\android-ndk-r10d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r10d
SDK_ROOT = D:\Android\android-sdk
```

I didnt set `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` environment variable as the tutorial that I followed did not set it. [ However if I set it the same value as NDK_ROOT, I get the error that `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT` variable does not point to the directory]

I am testing cpp-empty-test project [android]

Now the issue is that when i give the command "./ndkgdb.sh" through cygwin terminal, it gives me the error that the awk file is not found.

To my understanding It is finding it at the wrong path. It is trying to find the awk file from within the Project folder while the awk files are placed inside the ndk folders.

Where am I doing wrong? 
Your anticipated help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Edited:

My test project is placed at the following path

```
D:\Android\Cocos2dx\cocos2d-x-3.5\cocos2d-x-3.5\tests\cpp-empty-test
```

and the awk file is available here

```
D:\Android\Cocos2dx\android-ndk-r10d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r10d\build\awk
```

awk: fatal cannot find source file at

```
cygwin/D:\Android\Cocos2dx\cocos2d-x-3.5\cocos2d-x-3.5\tests\cpp-empty-test\proj.android\D:\Android\Cocos2dx\android-ndk-r10d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r10d
```

Comment: I don't know what any ogf the above is talking about BUT that error message isn't saying that `awk` can't be found, it's saying that `awk` cannot find the file containing the script that it expects to execute. This is not an awk issue it's something to do with your environment/makefile/whatever is being executed that is calling awk and telling it to interpret a file that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see the Edited part. The awk source file is being referenced from the wrong path. BUt i am not getting the clue why is the path wrong. I am not creating the ndkgdb.sh myself. Then why is compiling the wrong path?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello friend i am also working on cocos2dx .. and i have done setup correctly and its working for me ... i am going to describe what i have done........it may help for you as well as others



=============cocos2dx android setup guide=====================================

-  check for these 6 things
   1-> adt
   2-> ndk
   3-> cocos2dx
   4-> Python 
   5-> cygwin (setup-x86_64)
   6-> jdk

// now do all steps one by one

1-> first create a specific folder where you want to setup android 
2-> copy all these files (which mentioned above) 
3-> extract adt
4-> extract ndk
5-> extract cocos2dx
6-> install python 
7-> install cygwin  (to install this you need internet connection ..so follow the steps under -- how to install cygwin)
8-> setup environment variable for cygwin -----
                  -to set this open environment variable which you find mycomputer->properties->advance settings->environment variable
                  - now find path variable and add the path of cygwin ex-- mine ic c:/cygwin64/bin
                  - add another variable for ndk   NDK_ROOT ->  mine is F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\android-ndk-r10d

9 -> check for java (jdk) for eclipse , if not then install java
10-> set environment variable -> edit path ---add path for java ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;
  at start of this path
 11->you have done android setup ;




 how to install cygbin
 =============================

 -> double click on cygbin file->click next->next->next->next->next-
 -> now select mirror any one i choose http://cygbin.mirror.constant.com
 -> click next
 -> now u got select package -> search for the following one by one
       autoconf, automake, binutils, gcc-core, gcc-g**, gcc4-core, gcc4-g**, gdb, pcre, pcre-devel, gawk, make


       neccesory packages--->   make 

       ->and follow the instructions


======================================     
    finally ... you have done with setup now open elipse
    import your project -race track->proj.android
    import libcocos2dx--->   CoCos2Dx\cocos2dx\platform\android\java

now open cygbin.bat file-> go to you project resourse directory -> run command --   chmod -R 777 *  
    clean your project and run








==============================================================================================================
    CREATE NEW PROJECT IN COCOS2DX BY COMMAND PROMPT
==============================================================================================================  


    1-> open cmd
    2-> 

    go to path--CoCos2Dx\tools\project-creator   ( MINE WAS F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\tools\project-creator)
      now typing   cd above path  then press enter 
      now type f:  press enter
 3-> type command   create_project.py -project MyGame -package com.sensiblemobiles.mygame -language cpp
 then press enter

 4-> you have done with this. a project is created in cocos2dx/projects  folder
 5-> now to add this project in adt follow istruction (HOWW TO ADD COCOS2DX PROJECT IN ADT






=============================================================================================================== 
                        HOW TO ADD COCOS2DX PROJECT IN ADT
==============================================================================================================

follow thest steps to import a cocos2dx project for android in adt eclipse



1->  open eclipse go to file->import->Existing android code into workspace (under android tab) ->click next-> click on Browse
2-> Go to your project root folder like MyGame->proj.android
3-> finish  , your project will be added into project explorer


4-> to enable cocos2dx you need to import libcocos2dx follow above instruction same and go to root directory by following below path

 ->  CoCos2Dx\cocos2dx\platform\android\java    (F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\cocos2dx\platform\android\java)

5-> now add this libcocos2dx in to your project
   -> right click on your project ->properties->click android tab ->  click add button -> select libcocos2dx -> ok -> apply ->ok

6-> Now to see your classes in this project follow below instruction

  -> right click on your project -> properties -> explore resourse tab -> linked resourse -> path variables -> Now click on add (a dialog will be Open)
      - Name   :  COCOS2DX
      - Location : enter path of your cocos2dx   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx)
     -   click ok  -> again OK

7-> you need some more steps below

        -> right click on your project -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> select Code Analysis -> select Use Project Setting -> now uncheck Syntax and Symantic errors -> apply -> ok 

8-> Add path of cocosdension

 again go to your project -> right click -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> Path and Symbol -> selsect Include Tab -> select GNU++ -> click on Add button 
        -> fill dialog box  paste path of cocos2dx/cocosdension / include   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\CocosDenshion\include)        
        - press ok -> apply -> ok 

9->Now go to Project Tab of adt -> clean your project

10-> finally you have done 



=============================================================================================================================
     NOW MAKE FEW CHANGES TO YOUR ANDROID.MK FILE
=============================================================================================================================
EXPLORE YOUR PROJECT -> JNI -> ANDROID.MK

 NOTE :  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

            BELOW THE ABOVE LINES YOU HAVE TO ADD ALL CPP FILES LIKE ABOVE WITHOUT ANY SPACES 



===============================================================================================================================
         ENABLE BOX 2D IF YOU WANT TO USE BOX2D
===============================================================================================================================
FOLLOW ALL THE ABOVE STEPS TO CREATE NEW PROJECT AND IMPORT IT IN ADT ECLIPSE ;

NOW FOLLOW SOME MORE STEPS TO ENABLE BOX2D;


1->     right click on your project -> properties -> explore resourse tab -> linked resourse -> path variables -> Now click on add (a dialog will be Open)
      - Name   :  Box2D
      - Location : enter path of your Box2d   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D)
     -   click ok  -> again OK   

2->   now include box2d in include  
        again go to your project -> right click -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> Path and Symbol -> selsect Include Tab -> select GNU++ -> click on Add button 
        -> fill dialog box  paste path of \CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D)      
        - press ok -> apply -> ok 

3->         now add Box2D source 

            again go to your project -> right click -> explore  tab C/c++ General -> Path and Symbol -> select Source Location Tab -> select Link Folder -> check the chek box
        ->   paste path of \CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D   (mine was F:\myworkspace\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\CoCos2Dx\external\Box2D)     
        - press ok -> apply -> ok 

4-> change in application.mk file 

    EXPLORE YOUR PROJECT -> JNI -> application.mk
        replace this line (     APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1)
        to -- APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=0 -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1 -DCC_ENABLE_BOX2D_INTEGRATION=1

Note -> this will enable Box2d and disable chipmunk 
  finaly save this file     

 5->   change in android.mk file 

    EXPLORE YOUR PROJECT -> JNI -> android.mk

      after this line (LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes) with "space" 
        add path of box2d like ($(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../external/Box2D) after the line 

Note -> this will include Box2d  
  finalLy save this file        

 6-> ok you have done with box2d .   clean your project an enjoy... best of luck



 =============================================================================================================================================
 REMEMBER   FEW THINGS 
 ============================================================================================================================================

 1-> ADD NEW CLASS IN CLASSES FOLDER
 2-> ADD ALL RESOURCE INTO RESOURSEC FOLDER
 3-> AFTER ADDING NEW RESOURE REFRESH YOUR ANDROID PROJECT THEN RUN (PERMISSION) COMMAND INTO CYGWIN
       (cygbin.bat file-> go to you project resourse directory -> run command --   chmod -R 777 *   )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I am already doing all this. I wonder didnt the setup asked you to define ANDROID_NDK_ROOT environment variable? If I dont set it up, I get the error that ANDROID_NDK_ROOT is not point to a valid directory. If I set it up to the sme folder as NDK_ROOT is, I get the error that awk is not found.